# Facing issue in sorting a matrix by a measure in my situation

Tags: sorting, matrix, powerbi, dashboard, powerbi-desktop

I am facing issues in sorting a matrix by a measure. The problem is as follows:

[image]

[image]

Where:

Measure 1 =SUMX(Table1,[Column C] + [Column D])

I have a matrix with following Field Placement:

Rows: Column A, Column B

Column: Values (Table 2)

Values: Measure 2

Where:

Measure 2=IF(Table2[Index]=1,table1[Column C],IF(Table2[Index=2,Table1[Column D],IF(Table2[Index]=3,[Measure1])))

I got the matrix as follows:

[image]

Now I want to sort this matrix by Measure 1

Comment: Your `Measure 2` appears to be a calculated column rather than a measure.

Comment: No it is a measure

Comment: A measure with the DAX formula you gave for Measure 2 would give an error since there is no row context to determine a single value for the index.

Comment: I am using this dax for that:
IF(average(Table2[Index])=1,table1[Column C],IF(average(Table2[Index])=2,Table1[Column D],IF(average(Table2[Index])=3,[Measure1])))

Which is working fine

Comment: Yes, if that DAX is working, then it cannot be a measure. You can only use row context like that with a calculated column.